# Feather theme showing `Dimension too large.` error for more than 74 frames

Tags: beamer

In my beamer presentation with "Feather theme", when I exceed 74 frames, the following error will appear:

[image: dimension too large].

If I delete frames, the problem disappears. Can someone help me without deleting any frames?

A minimal reproducible example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Feather}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\begin{document}

\foreach \macro in {1,...,75}{
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: show the  actual error from the log file, the editor summary you show is not very helpful as it omits all the context information about where the error is

Answer (score 1):

You could patch the `\feathergeaderbackground` macro to use the tikz `fpu` library.

The code to do this can be found in this question: https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=4494 (might not be the original source)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Feather}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fpu,calc}

% from https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=4494 
\def\pgfmathsetmacroFPU#1#2{\begingroup%
    \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{#1}{#2}%
    \pgfmathsmuggle#1\endgroup}%

\patchcmd{\featherheaderbackground}{
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\progress}{220*\insertframestartpage/\inserttotalframenumber};
}{
 \pgfmathsetmacroFPU{\progress}{220*\insertframestartpage/\inserttotalframenumber}
}{}{}

\patchcmd{\featherheaderbackground}{
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\progress}{-220*\insertframestartpage/\inserttotalframenumber}; 
}{
 \pgfmathsetmacroFPU{\progress}{-220*\insertframestartpage/\inserttotalframenumber}
}{}{}


\begin{document}

\foreach \macro in {1,...,100}{
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}
}

\end{document}
```

(I also removed some incorrectly placed `;` to avoid the log file getting flooded by warnings about missing null fonts....)